# Angularjs SEO: is making html snapshots required anymore?

Tags: angularjs, seo

As Google announced "Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers", does it mean even if we do not generate html snapshot on server and serve to Googlebot, it will crawl our site developed by using angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true Google doesn't need it anymore.

But other services might use it. See: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86262/should-we-drop-ajax-crawling-scheme